Why do my cards stop rendering sometimes?
I'm a junior developer, and I created a drinking game, a type of "Dare or Drink." I used the T3 Create App with TypeScript, Drizzle, and PostgreSQL.
The problem is that my application fetches a value and cards but then stops rendering them. Sometimes it stops after one or two cards, other times it goes up to eight, and then it just stops rendering. I have to refresh the site for it to work again.
I don't get any error logs or anything; the console even shows that the query was executed successfully, but it just doesn’t work.
'use client'

import '@/styles/gameStyle.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react"
import { api } from "@/trpc/react"
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { useMotionValue, useDragControls, motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"
import Card from "../components/card/card"
import DialogInfoModal from "../components/game/dialogInfoModal"
import PlayButton from "../components/game/PlayButton"
import PlayerForm from "../components/game/PlayerForm"
import DeckChoose from "../components/game/DeckChoose"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { useToast } from "@/hooks/use-toast"
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react"

export default function Game() {
  const [selectedDeckIds, setSelectedDeckIds] = useState<string[]>([])
  const [gameStage, setGameStage] = useState<'initial' | 'deckChoose' | 'playerForm' | 'gamePlay'>('initial')
  const [currentMatchId, setCurrentMatchId] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [playersList, setPlayersList] = useState<{ id: string; name: string }[]>([])
  const [currentPlayerIndex, setCurrentPlayerIndex] = useState(0)
  const [exitX, setExitX] = useState(0)

  const x = useMotionValue(0)
  const dragControls = useDragControls()

  const { toast } = useToast()

  const { data: cardData, refetch, isLoading: isCardLoading, error: cardError } = api.card.getRandomCardByDeckId.useQuery(
    { deckIds: selectedDeckIds },
    {
      enabled: selectedDeckIds.length > 0 && gameStage === 'gamePlay',
      retry: false,
      onError: (error) => {
        toast({ description: 'Error fetching card: ' + error.message, variant: "destructive" })
      }
    }
  )

  const { mutate: playerMutate } = api.players.create.useMutation()
  const { mutate: matchesMutate, isLoading: isMatchMutating } = api.match.create.useMutation({
    onSuccess: (matchData) => {
      setCurrentMatchId(matchData.id)
      console.log('Match created with ID:', matchData.id)
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast({ description: 'Erro ao criar partida: ' + error.message, variant: "destructive" })
    }
  })

  const { mutate: matchPlayersMutate } = api.matchPlayers.create.useMutation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameStage === 'gamePlay' && selectedDeckIds.length > 0) {
      refetch()
    }
  }, [gameStage, selectedDeckIds, refetch])

  const handlePlayButtonClick = () => {
    setGameStage('deckChoose')
    createMatch()
  }

  const handlePlayerForm = () => {
    setGameStage('gamePlay')
  }

  const createMatch = () => {
    const date = new Date()
    const status = 'Started'
    matchesMutate({ status, date })
  }

  const handlePlayerSubmit = (name: string) => {
    const id = uuidv4()

    playerMutate({ id, name }, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        toast({ description: 'Jogador Adicionado com Sucesso!' })
        setPlayersList((prev) => [...prev, { id, name }])
        if (currentMatchId) {
          matchPlayersMutate({
            matchId: currentMatchId,
            playerId: id,
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }

  const handleDeckSelection = useCallback((chosenDeckIds: string[]) => {
    setSelectedDeckIds(chosenDeckIds)
    setGameStage('playerForm')
  }, [])

  const handleDragEnd = (
    _: MouseEvent | TouchEvent | PointerEvent,
    info: { offset: { x: number } }
  ) => {
    if (info.offset.x < -150 || info.offset.x > 150) {
      setExitX(info.offset.x < -150 ? -400 : 400)
      console.log(info.offset.x < -150 ? 'esquerda' : 'direita')

      setCurrentPlayerIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % playersList.length)
      refetch()
    }
  }

  return (
    <main className="relative main flex h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-b from-[#15042e] to-[#070012]">
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        {gameStage === 'initial' && (
          <motion.div
            key="playButton"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          >
            <PlayButton onClick={handlePlayButtonClick} />
          </motion.div>
        )}

        {gameStage === 'deckChoose' && (
          <motion.div
            key="deckChoose"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          >
            <DeckChoose onDeckSelection={handleDeckSelection} />
          </motion.div>
        )}

        {gameStage === 'playerForm' && (
          <motion.div
            key="playerForm"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          >
            <PlayerForm setPlayerFormVisible={handlePlayerForm} onSubmit={handlePlayerSubmit} playersList={playersList} />
          </motion.div>
        )}

        {gameStage === 'gamePlay' && (
          <motion.div
            key="gamePlay"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
            className="w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
          >
            <h2 className="text-white mb-4 absolute top-20 text-xl font-semibold">Turno de: {playersList[currentPlayerIndex]?.name}</h2>

            <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full h-full">
              {isCardLoading ? (
                <Loader2 className="h-8 w-8 animate-spin" />
              ) : cardError ? (
                <div className="text-center">
                  <p className="text-red-500 mb-4">Error: {cardError.message}</p>
                  <Button onClick={() => refetch()}>Tente Novamente</Button>
                </div>
              ) : cardData && cardData.length > 0 ? (
                <AnimatePresence>
                  {cardData.map((data) => (
                    <Card
                      key={data.id ?? uuidv4()}
                      drag="x"
                      cardDescription={data.description ?? ''}
                      cardNumber={data.level ?? 0}
                      cardTheme={data.theme ?? ''}
                      cardName={data.name ?? ''}
                      cardSubtitle={data.subtitle ?? ''}
                      x={x}
                      dragControls={dragControls}
                      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                    />
                  ))}
                </AnimatePresence>
              ) : (
                <p className="text-white">Sem Cartas Nesse Deck</p>
              )}
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>

      <div className="absolute bottom-8 right-8">
        <DialogInfoModal />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}


That's the Game Page Component.
import { z } from "zod";
import { createTRPCRouter, publicProcedure } from "@/server/api/trpc";
import { cards } from "@/server/db/schema";
import { db } from "@/server/db/index"
import { sql, inArray } from "drizzle-orm";

export async function getRandomCardByDeckIds(deckIds: string[]) {
    if (deckIds.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("No deck IDs provided");
    }

    const query = sql`
        SELECT * FROM "pinga-party_card"
        WHERE ${inArray(cards.deckId, deckIds)}
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 1
    `;

    return await db.execute(query);
}

export async function getRandomCard() {
    return await db.execute(sql`SELECT * FROM "pinga-party_card" ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1`);
}

export const cardRouter = createTRPCRouter({
    getRandomCardByDeckId: publicProcedure
        .input(z.object({
            deckIds: z.array(z.string())
        }))
        .query(async ({ input }) => {
            return await getRandomCardByDeckIds(input.deckIds);
        }),

    getRandomCard: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
        return await getRandomCard();
    }),

    get: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
        return await db.query.cards.findMany({
            with: {
                deck: true,
            },
        });
    }),

    create: publicProcedure
        .input(
            z.object({
                name: z.string(),
                description: z.string(),
                theme: z.string(),
                level: z.number().int(),
                deckId: z.string(),
                subtitle: z.string(),
            })
        )
        .mutation(async (opts) => {
            const { input } = opts;
            await db.insert(cards).values({
                name: input.name,
                description: input.description,
                theme: input.theme,
                level: input.level,
                deckId: input.deckId,
                subtitle: input.subtitle,
            })
        }),
})

And that's the model.
I already checked the database, but seems the problem might be somewhere in the code.
Anything needed I'll just send. I already tried logs, database, gpts like chatgpt, gemini, v0, without success.

Nice to meet you. I have read your issues and check your code.
I hope to can help you my solution.
Sure! Here are some potential reasons why your React.js and Next.js application might be fetching data but failing to render it, along with troubleshooting steps:

State Management Issues: Ensure that you are properly updating the component's state after fetching the data. If the state isn't updated correctly, the component won't re-render even though the data is fetched successfully.

Conditional Rendering Logic: Review the conditions under which the data is rendered. Ensure that your rendering logic correctly handles scenarios where data is not yet available or is being loaded.

Handling Asynchronous Fetch: Make sure your fetch logic is correctly handling promises and that you are managing loading states well. Proper error handling can also provide insights into issues.

Server-side and Static Props: If using Next.js features like getServerSideProps or getStaticProps, verify that these functions are returning the correct data to your component.

Rendering Lists: When rendering lists of data, confirm that each item has a unique key. This helps React track changes to the list and can impact rendering.

Context or State Management Tool Issues: If using context or state management libraries, ensure that components are correctly subscribed to updates.


If the issue persists after checking these areas, consider isolating parts of your application to identify the source of the problem.
If you want, I can solve your issues for a short time.

Is this LLM-generated text (which is expressly disallowed here)?

Seems like the answer is generated by AI chatbot like chatGpt or Gemini
